# Who said "crisis is the end of an illusion"?

Tags: reference-request

Which philosopher has stated "This is not the beginning of a crisis. This is the end of an illusion"? (approximate quote)

And if you remember the philosopher: from which context or book comes this quote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure that is the original source of the quote, but every reference points to [Gerald Weinberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_Weinberg).

The exact quote is: "It may look like a crisis, but it’s only the end of an illusion." It's from Weinberg's Book [The Secrets of Consulting: A Guide to Giving and Getting Advice Successfully](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0932633013).

Comment: I was looking for the original source of the quote.

Comment: @PhilippeBlayo I found no indices that this isn't the original. Why do you think there was another source? This could actually help searching.

Comment: a friend of mine read of this idea of crisis and illusion in the context of ancient Greek philosophy, but was not able to find this original source again.

Comment: perhaps my question should have been on the origin of the idea of linking crisis and illusion rather than on a specific quote.

Comment: @PhilippeBlayo Then maybe you should start with editing your question (:

Comment: Maybe he is thinking of the old idea (said by John F Kennedy) that the Chinese symbol for CRISIS consists of combining the symbols for DANGER and OPPORTUNITY ?